# Ui-bootstrap alerts do not show any color

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following ui-bootstrap code:

```
<alert close='closeAlert($index)' ng-repeat='alert in alerts' type='alert.type'>
        {{alert.msg}}
    </alert>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $scope.alerts.push({type: 'info', msg: 'Info received!'})
```

However, after posting, I don't see any colors, only the message in a white background. Any ideas what might be going wrong? I'm using angular 1.2.28, bootstrap 3.1.1 and ui-bootstrap 0.12.1.

Comment: is alert tag something angularjs thing?  I create bootstrap alerts using div class ="class="alert alert-info".  I guess you may try the div approach and than .push({class:'alert alert-info', msg:'Info received!'}).  But I may be wrong. or may be try pushing 'alert-info' instead of 'info'.

Comment: Yup the alert tag is an angularjs directive - more info here: https://coderwall.com/p/r_bvhg/angular-ui-bootstrap-alert-service-for-angular-js

Comment: I tried adding <div class="alert alert-info"> , and the color is shown when i do that, but it's shown prematurely, before the button triggering the alert is clicked. So looks like bootstrap is showing colors fine, but angular bootstrap is somehow not showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the type in braces:

```
<alert close="closeAlert($index)" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}">
    {{alert.msg}}
</alert>
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert